# Spring REST Exception - getting the response payload

Tags: rest, spring-boot, error-handling

I have the following:
[image]

The "400 Bad request" is converted to a ResourceAccessException in Spring.

Is there any way to retrieve the payload here? I want to send the "errorMessage" further up the call chain.

Code-wise the following is used to do the request:

```
    public <T> T post(String url, Object request, Class<T> className) {
    try {
        return logEnhancedRestTemplate.postForObject(url, request, className);
    } catch(RestClientException ex) {
        throw handleErrors(ex, url);
    }
}
```

It is in the "handleErrors" method I want to use the "errorMessage" from the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the message of an exception use the method `getMessage()`.

In your specific example maybe is better if you catch a generic exception, since I suppose that every type of Runtime exception should call your method `handleErrors(ex, url)`.

If this is the case, I suggest you to modify your code with:

```
public <T> T post(String url, Object request, Class<T> className) {
  try {
      return logEnhancedRestTemplate.postForObject(url, request, className);
  } catch(Exception ex) {
      throw handleErrors(ex, url);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would have thought so too, unfortunately the getMessage() does not give back the body/payload of the response, rather something like "I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8080/api-extensions/catalogues": Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL..."